# Conditionally rendering multiple components -- which style is more readable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider a web app page where there's table of data that I can edit if I have sufficient permissions. For this example, our editing is limited to selecting and deleting rows.

Which of the following two approaches for the `render` method of each table row is more readable?

```
render() {
  let checkbox, deleteButton;

  if (CAN_EDIT) {
    checkbox = (
      <checkbox-button-stuff
      ... this is an 8 line declaration
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      />
    );

    deleteButton = (
      <delete-button-stuff           
      ... this is a 9 line declaration
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      />
    );
  }

  return (
     <div>
       {checkbox}
       <other-table-stuff />
       {deleteButton}
     </div>
  );
}
```

or

```
render() {
  let checkbox = (
      <checkbox-button-stuff           
      ... this is a 9 line declaration
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      />
  );

  let deleteButton = (
      <delete-button-stuff
      ... this is an 9 line declaration
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      ...
      />
  );

  if (!CAN_EDIT) {
    checkbox = null;
    deleteButton = null;
  }

  return (
     <div>
       {checkbox}
       <other-table-stuff />
       {deleteButton}
     </div>
  );
}
```

Note: the `*-stuff` names are used to represent nested `divs` + other components. Also, I say that the buttons are an "X line declaration" because this is based on actual code review from a PR that I made.

I'd argue that the latter keeps the logic of "should I render these?" in one place. The first example, however, avoids the negation (`!CAN_EDIT`) which IMO hurts readability.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: The first one look more cleaner , but again it just a mater of prefrence

Comment: Preferable to whom?

Comment: @Adam I renamed the title, because I would consider readability to be fairly objective (more than "preferable" at least).

Comment: Neither option seems great. Have you read the conditional rendering article? https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a third option:

```
return (
  <div>
    { CAN_EDIT && <CheckboxButtonStuff /> }
    <OtherTableStuff />
    { CAN_EDIT && <DeleteButtonStuff /> }
  </div>
);
```

Also your components should be capitalized and preferably camel cased- https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: If the components were actually this small, I'd use this inline approach, but each `*-button-stuff` is actually ~8 lines long. ~(There's an argument to be made for pulling them out into separate components, but that's beside the point)~ I just checked the code review this is based on -- the length of each component comes from setting some props and passing in a child component.

Comment: Are they that long because you're passing a lot of props to them?

Comment: @Galupf Yeah, I'm passing 3-4 props to each. Between the wrapping `td` tag and the `button`'s child, each one is pretty long.

Comment: Are the props to pass to each one the same or at least similar?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

For inline if else test in React, you can use :

```
render() {
    { 
        <div>
            MY_CONDITION ?
                <MyComponentToRenderIfTrue />
            : 
                <MyOtherComponentToRenderIfFalse />
        </div>
    }
}
```

OR

```
render() {
    { 

        <div>
            MY_CONDITION && <MyComponentToRender />
        </div>
    }
}
```

In both, you can update your **MY_CONDITION** and React will re-render your component.

Hope this help.